# 'File is corrupted' when opening docx file when created in C

Tags: c

I am using "UNIX" (on my virtual machine) and generating ".docx" file there using "C", after getting the file into Windows, when I am opening the file it's saying "the file is corrupted, can't be opened" and then its not opening. 
I am using MS-Word 2010.

Here is the piece of code I am using:-

```
Write_to_file(){
 FILE *fp;
 if((fp=fopen("hello.docx","w"))==(FILE*)NULL){
  printf("Error opening file");
  return 0;
 }
 fprintf(fp,"Hello World");
 fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: your code is wrong `If` should be `if`

Comment: open the file in notepad or gedit ! the file you created is not a msword file , it has only .doc extension ... you are far away! .doc files are so special and you have to go deep!

Comment: Neither a `.doc` file nor a `.docx` file is plain text. The `.docx` format (or, at least one variant of it) is documented [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) [Warning: insanely huge PDFs containing ridiculously complex specifications].

Comment: I am not familiar with docx format, but you can't just pass any ascii string and add extension .doc to create doc files..

Comment: Extension mean nothing. It is the format in which the data is stored in the file denote the filetype, most often identified by a "magic number" at the starting of the file. In this case what you have in the file is just a string of characters which has no special interpretation, and thus considered as a plaintext file.

Comment: Also @avinashse don't just workaround by using incorrect spelling of a banned word in title. Words like **Problem** banned in question title because of a specific reason.. You could write a better title, by simply avoiding that word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just with an extension name (doc docx) does not make the file a MS word file. Your code is only writing a text file. You can dectect this by file command under Linux.

Please reference this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105(v=office.12).aspx, and write the **REAL** MS document file.

Answer (score 4):

A `doc` file is not a simple text file. You'd want to use the `txt` format:

```
fopen("hello.txt", "w");
```

To actually read/write a `doc` file, you'd  need to use a library designed specifically to read them and write them.

[The spec for MS-DOC files is pretty lengthy, so I wouldn't implement my own reader/writer if I were you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx)